# Force audio to play through Headphones - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, windows-registry

I have a hardware problem. Jack sensor in my laptop is not working. It doesn't detect a plugged jack.
In Ubuntu, I used to force audio to play through headphones using this command:

```
pacmd set-sink-port 0 analog-output-headphones
```

In Windows 7, I am looking for a registry key to change or any other solution to change the default audio device from "Speakers" to "Headphones". I don't use my laptop's speakers anyway.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4C3G.png)

Comment: Hi, is it Windows 7 32 bit or 64bit? I think you can find the registry key for 32 bit on HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Sound Mapper

Comment: It's Windows 7 x64